# How can i resolve N: Skipping acquire of configured file '.. doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

How can I resolve issue 
xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Answer (score 8):

I got same error,Solved by adding **[arch=amd64]**  to

**`deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe`**

> Just locate `etc/apt/sources.list` **Edit file & just add above line**

or

> **Edit existing line by adding  `[arch=amd64]` after `deb` as per your current version**

Comment: This direction helped me. When adding the Docker repo I accidentally typed `[arch=emd64]`. This caused a similar error shown above. I edited the `etc/apt/sources.list` file for a fix.